# interpret payoff

Tags: black-scholes-merton

How can the payoff f = min(max(S - K1, 0), K2) be interpreted?

Comment: How can the payoff f = min(max(S - K1, 0), K2) be interpreted?

Comment: Is this homework? I would say the title and the question don't match because I think you are asked to compute the price and delta of an option. Please try to use mathjax, it makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: Please be more specific about your question (and what stumps you), do not expect an answer just by posting the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$min(max(S-K_1,0),K_2)=max(S-K_1,0)-max(S-(K_1+K_2),0)$$ so this is the payoff of a call spread (you're long the $K_1$ strike and short a $K_1+K_2$ strike). Then you can use standard Black-Scholes on each option to get your results.